# Слежка в Windows 10

Tags: безопасность, windows-10

В Windows 10 есть много средств сбора данных/телеметрии. Их можно отключать в настройках и специальными программами.

**Есть ли другие скрытые методы слежки, которые не отключаются? может ли Вин10 анализировать мои файлы на дисках, действия, скрытно, нестандартными (скрытными) методами, передавать подобные данные полностью незаметно для любых программных анализаторов сети?**

---

( второстепенный вопрос: )

( Может ли Microsoft, например, при полит. решении послать сигнал на компьютеры Вин10 с командой, например, удалить все, что-либо напортить и тому подобное? )

( Код ОС закрыт, из того точно ответить может быть затруднительно. Но есть же спец.службы надзора за подобными вещами... говорят ли что-либо они? )

---

_Обновл.

Спасибо тем, кто успел ответить до блокировки вопроса, что было предсказуемо. Я, все таки, надеялся, что найдется кто-то именно с техническими знаниями данного вопроса. Я не имел ввиду "боязнь". Так же интересно если есть какие либо сертификации виндовс а данном вопросе в наших краях и т.п.

Если уж начали упоминать догадки, моя - в виндовсе есть анализ данных устройства и скрытая передача общих данных в каком-то виде о всем (не конкретно за кем-то), как-то это храниться, анализируется... ну, как фантазия. Но, опять же, я надеялся о глубоко техническом ответе, если вообще возможен (учитывая, что для этого скорее всего нужно дизассемблировать MS файлы...)

Comment: Хозяин-барин => авторы ОС что угодно могут спрятать "за кулисами". В свое время SONY собирали информацию об используемых телевизорах через SONY PlayStation 3.

Comment: Как это относится к программированию? Если вы боитесь слежки, то можете отдохнуть, я думаю конкретно вы им не нужны. Я лично использую linux.

Answer (score 4):

Не бойтесь слежки... Не думаю, что Microsoft заинтересована в "слежке" именно за вами или вообще есть возможность следить за более чем  1 млрд юзеров. Да и зачем отправлять данные, если пользователь сам выложит в соц. сети и т.п ресурсы. Чтобы Вами заинтересовали органы для этого нужны серьёзные основания или сумма больше 6 нулей на Вашем банковском счете. А вообще, конечно у нее есть службы, какие не отображаются в общем потоке.

Насчет вопроса второго - ну конечно может. Ведь компания как-то проводит обновление системы( методом создания, перезаписи и удаления файлов), по этому в теории ей не составит труда стереть все у Вас. Вот только зачем?

Comment: Как пример осеннее "кривое" обновление когда папка "Мои документы" обнулялась :-)

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас нет паранойи это ещё не значит что за вами никто не следит?

А вас не беспокоит что же там такое загадочное компания Интел напихала в свои процессоры?

Или производители вашего роутера в прошивку?

Порой не порча данных а просто отказ может быть очень печальным. Или как в Иране было со stuxnet.

У министерства обороны Российской Федерации на это такое мнение: сертификация.

Естественно она должна быть квалифицированная, чтобы были какие-то гарантии.

Но все равно уровень паранойи может быть доведён до абсурда и будет как в футураме, когда бендер стал деревянным. :)